# Can I pass custom annotation parameters to Spring EL expression?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have custom annotations such as:

```
@AllowedForUserWithID
public myFunction (int userID) {       
}

@PreAuthorize(CustomPermissionEvaluator.isUserWithID(principal, #userID))
public @interface AllowedForUserWithID {
}

public static boolean isUserWithID(UserDetails user, Integer userID) {
}
```

These are working fine, and I can get method arguments using '#'.

However, my aim is to have an annotation as follows:

```
@RequiresPermission(feature=SecurityFeature.SETTINGS, rights=AccessRights.WRITE)
public myFunction() {
}

@PreAuthorize(CustomPermissionEvaluator.hasAccessPermission(principal, feature, rights))
public @interface RequiresPermission {
    SecurityFeature feature();
    AccessRights rights();
}

public static boolean hasAccessPermission(UserDetails user, SecurityFeature feature, AccessRights rights) {
}
```

Is it possible to pass the parameters into the expression in this way?