# Spring security new method level annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm working on securing a REST Service endpoints with Spring Security. I basically need to check if user has given Authority, if the user can invoke the function with the given parameters, and lastly, I filter the output, so that the user cannot see things that it shouldn't.

For this, I have this set of annotations:

`@PostFilter("#canViewOwnAssignment.canView(filterObject) or #canViewAllAssignments.canView(filterObject)")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('canViewOwnAssignment', 'canViewAllAssignments') and (#canViewOwnAssignment.canEnter(userId) or #canViewAllAssignments.canEnter(userId))")`

...for all the methods. The only thing changing from the above snippet is *canViewOwnAssignment* and the parameter(s) of *.canEnter()*.

I'd like to simplify this, so that I can have an annotation looking sg like this:`@MyAnnotation(bean = CanViewAssignment.class, args = {"userId"})`

How could I make this happen?

I tried extending PrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource.class, since that's the one parsing the annotations, however I can't just use @Primary to override it, since the bean instantiation is baked into the GlobalMethodSecurityDefinitionParser.class

If I don't need to,  I'd rather not start rewriting half of the Spring Security, only to have one overriden method.

Comment: You might try to define a `BeanPostProcessor` implementation that later on adds the respective information via reflection to the annotated method. A sample of how something can look like can be seen [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-annotation-bean-pre-processor)

Comment: There are some similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18097152/custom-annotation-with-spring-security, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45090693/how-to-write-custom-preauthorize-annotation-and-intercepter and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33784202/can-i-pass-custom-annotation-parameters-to-spring-el-expression. All without an answer. Hence, it is very likely that there isn't a way.